# How to install xmlrpc in php 8.0 MACOS

Tags: php, odoo, xml-rpc

**Hello**

I need to connect an application with PHP 8.0 to Odoo. And I get the following error.

```
PHP XMLRPC library is not installed
```

How can I install this library on macOS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please do not use the xmlrpc php extension from PECL. It is as close to abandonware as it possibly could.

You should rather use a pure-php implementation of the xmlrpc protocol.

If you can not use a different pure-php xmlrpc library, because you are using an app which uses the API of the PECL extension, you are better off using https://github.com/gggeek/polyfill-xmlrpc instead. It can be installed using `composer require phpxmlrpc/polyfill-xmlrpc`

Answer (score 3):

[I found the solution in this post](https://php.watch/versions/8.0/xmlrpc)

Must be installed via PECL

Use this command

```
pecl install channel://pecl.php.net/xmlrpc-1.0.0RC3
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Does not work for me either